# SQL Order by group of specific values

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I tried to found the solution, I might have done wrong researches, that's why I need your help :(

There is 6 different categorie, with different values. I want to select all of them, but ordered in 2 differents groups : the first would contain all between 1 and 3, ordered by another value.
Always in the same request, I want to display category between 4 and 6, ordered by another value.

The better way is to show you before and after, what I would like :

BEFORE

```
|Category | name     |
|    1    | Barney   |
|    6    | Ted      |
|    6    | Anita    |
|    3    | Jessica  |
|    2    | Marshall |
|    3    | Lily     |
|    4    | Robin    |
|    2    | Bryan    |
|    5    | Oliver   |
```

AFTER

```
|Category | name     | ----- Alphabetic sort
|    1    | Barney   |
|    2    | Bryan    |
|    3    | Jessica  |
|    3    | Lily     |
|    2    | Marshall |
---------------------------Imaginary line which seperate 2 groups : category 1 2 3 and 4 5 6
|    6    | Anita    |
|    5    | Oliver   |
|    4    | Robin    |
|    6    | Ted      |
```

I hope you understood what I meaned !

Thank you for your help !

Comment: which RDMS are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY CASE  
            WHEN category IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1
            WHEN category IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 2
            ELSE 3
         END,
         name
```

The query uses a `CASE` expression in order to group together `category` subsets: subset `1`, `2`, `3` is assigned a value of `1` and hence has the greatest priority. Subset   `4`, `5`, `6` is assigned a value of `2`, whereas the rest of categories get the lowest priority, i.e. the value of `3`.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know to what corresponds 1 2 and 3? Columns? Thank you !

Comment: @NolweenLopez There are `category` values. Please check the edit I made.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL or PostgreSQL you can easily get this by using `ORDER BY category>3, name`, assuming there are only these two possible groups.

Comment: For which DBMS is this? Which DBMS sorts booleans with true before false?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks, brainfart. Fixed the comparison.

Comment: This still doesn't work in many DBMS. I suppose this is meant for MySQL (for MySQL's special treatment of booleans where true equals 1 and false equals 0)?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm used to PostgreSQL knowing how to order by booleans and as you said MySQL also handles this (due to their implementation). Doesn't work in every engine, that is true.

Answer (score 1):

In your `SELECT` statement try:

`... ORDER BY IF(Category<4,0,1) ASC, name ASC`

Comment: `IF`? This is no standard SQL function. For which DBMS is this?

Comment: It is in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if